# Codable enum with multiple keys and associated values

Tags: swift, enums, codable

I've seen answers on how to make an enum conform to Codable when all cases have an associated value, but I'm not clear on how to mix enums that have cases with and without associated values:

??? How can I use multiple variations of the same key for a given case?

??? How do I encode/decode cases with no associated value?

```
enum EmployeeClassification : Codable, Equatable {

case aaa
case bbb
case ccc(Int) // (year)

init?(rawValue: String?) {
    guard let val = rawValue?.lowercased() else {
        return nil
    }
    switch val {
        case "aaa", "a":
            self = .aaa
        case "bbb":
            self = .bbb
        case "ccc":
            self = .ccc(0)
        default: return nil
    }
}

// Codable
private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
    case aaa // ??? how can I accept "aaa", "AAA", and "a"?
    case bbb
    case ccc
}

init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
    let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    if let value = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .ccc) {
        self = .ccc(value)
        return
    }
    // ???
    // How do I decode the cases with no associated value?
}
func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
    var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
    switch self {
    case .ccc(let year):
        try container.encode(year, forKey: .ccc)
    default:
        // ???
        // How do I encode cases with no associated value?
    }
}
}
```

Comment: You can not have multiple cases with same name in any conditions, but you can initial a single case from multiple `raw values`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use the assumed raw string values of the init method as (string) value of the enum case

```
enum EmployeeClassification : Codable, Equatable {
    
    case aaa
    case bbb
    case ccc(Int) // (year)
    
    init?(rawValue: String?) {
        guard let val = rawValue?.lowercased() else {
            return nil
        }
        switch val {
        case "aaa", "a":
            self = .aaa
        case "bbb":
            self = .bbb
        case "ccc":
            self = .ccc(0)
        default: return nil
        }
    }
    
    // Codable
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey { case aaa, bbb, ccc }
    
    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        if let value = try? container.decode(Int.self, forKey: .ccc) {
            self = .ccc(value)
        } else if let aaaValue = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .aaa), ["aaa", "AAA", "a"].contains(aaaValue) {
            self = .aaa
        } else if let bbbValue = try? container.decode(String.self, forKey: .bbb), bbbValue == "bbb" {
            self = .bbb
        } else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorrupted(DecodingError.Context(codingPath: container.codingPath, debugDescription: "Data doesn't match"))
        }
    }
    
    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        switch self {
        case .aaa: try container.encode("aaa", forKey: .aaa)
        case .bbb: try container.encode("bbb", forKey: .bbb)
        case .ccc(let year): try container.encode(year, forKey: .ccc)
        }
    }
}
```

The Decoding Error is quite generic. You can throw more specific errors for each CodingKey

Comment: This is brilliant, so much less complex than all the blogs I've seen trying some crazy stuff. . I had a "solution" that was close to yours but didn't work. The missing piece was the init?(rawValue: String?) method.

Comment: Great answer! Helps me a lot.

Answer (score 3):

Starting with Swift 5.5, enums with associated values gained the ability of having automatic conformance to `Codable`. See [this](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0295-codable-synthesis-for-enums-with-associated-values.md) swift-evolution proposal for more details about the implementation details.

So, this is enough for your enum:

```swift
enum EmployeeClassification : Codable, Equatable {
    case aaa
    case bbb
    case ccc(Int) // (year)
```

No more `CodingKeys`, no more `init(from:)`, or `encode(to:)`

Answer (score 2):

Thanks @vadian for the great answer

Another way how to implement custom Decodable / Encodable methods for any enum with associated value and (or) empty cases – using approach with the `nestedContainer` method called from the root `container`.

That way describes in the Swift Evolution proposal for Swift 5.5 the support for auto-synthesis of `Codable` conformance to enums with associated values.
All details and the next implementation I got from the proposal you can also take a look: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0295-codable-synthesis-for-enums-with-associated-values.md

I also extend example from the proposal to cover exactly author's question.

```
enum Command: Codable {
  case load(String)
  case store(key: String, Int)
  case eraseAll
}
```

The `encode(to:)` implementation for `Encodable` would look as follows:

```
public func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
  var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
  switch self {
  case let .load(key):
    var nestedContainer = container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .load)
    try nestedContainer.encode(key)
  case let .store(key, value):
    var nestedContainer = container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: StoreCodingKeys.self, forKey: .store)
    try nestedContainer.encode(key, forKey: .key)
    try nestedContainer.encode(value, forKey: .value)
  case .eraseAll:
    var nestedContainer = container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .eraseAll)
    try nestedContainer.encodeNil()
  }
}
```

Please pay attention on some modifications: (1) for `load` and `eraseAll`  cases I use `nestedUnkeyedContainer` instead suggested in proposal and `eraseAll` is the new case which I also added without an associated value.

and the `init(from:)` implementation for `Decodable` would look as follows:

```
public init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
  let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
  if container.allKeys.count != 1 {
    let context = DecodingError.Context(
      codingPath: container.codingPath,
      debugDescription: "Invalid number of keys found, expected one.")
    throw DecodingError.typeMismatch(Command.self, context)
  }

  switch container.allKeys.first.unsafelyUnwrapped {
  case .load:
    let nestedContainer = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .load)
    self = .load(try nestedContainer.decode(String.self))
  case .store:
    let nestedContainer = try container.nestedContainer(keyedBy: StoreCodingKeys.self, forKey: .store)
    self = .store(
      key: try nestedContainer.decode(String.self, forKey: .key),
      value: try nestedContainer.decode(Int.self, forKey: .value))
  case .eraseAll:
    _ = try container.nestedUnkeyedContainer(forKey: .eraseAll)
    self = .eraseAll
  }
}
```