# Making an enum with associated values conform to decodable?

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to make my enumeration that has different associated values comply to the Decodable protocol, but am having trouble with the associated values part.

```
enum SportType: Decodable {
    case team(String, String) //Two team names
    case individual([String]) //List of player names
}
```

I have successfully gotten an enum to conform to Decodable without associated values, but am having trouble doing the same thing with the associated values.

```
//Works but no associated values
enum SportType: String, Decodable {
    case team, case individual
}
```

Comment: You need a custom init: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57643993/codable-enum-with-multiple-keys-and-associated-values

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create a custom `init(from decoder: Decoder) throws`, and treat your associated values like they are normal fields in the object, using `CodingKeys` to decode them. Details depend on how your associated values are actually represented in encoded object.

For example if your values are encoded as:

```
{ "team1": "aaa", "team2": "bbb" }
```

and

```
{ "individual": ["x", "y", "z"]}
```

You can:

```
enum SportType: Decodable {

    case team(String, String) //Two team names
    case individual([String]) //List of player names

    // Define associated values as keys
    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case team1
        case team2
        case individual
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {

        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        // Try to decode as team
        if let team1 = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .team1),
           let team2 = try container.decodeIfPresent(String.self, forKey: .team2) {
            self = .team(team1, team2)
            return
        }

        // Try to decode as individual
        if let individual = try container.decodeIfPresent([String].self, forKey: .individual) {
            self = .individual(individual)
            return
        }

        // No luck
        throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .individual, in: container, debugDescription: "No match")
    }
}
```

Test:

```
let encoded = """
    { "team1": "aaa", "team2": "bbb" }
""".data(using: .utf8)

let decoded = try? JSONDecoder().decode(SportType.self, from: encoded!)

switch decoded {
case .team(let a, let b):
    print("I am a valid team with team1=\(a), team2=\(b)")
case .individual(let a):
    print("I am a valid individual with individual=\(a)")
default:
    print("I was not parsed :(")
}
```

Prints:

```
I am a valid team with team1=aaa, team2=bbb
```

Comment: Question was mostly around how to comply to `Decodable`, and main point of the answer is that OP needs an `init`. 
Regarding keyless decoding: yes, it may make sense in some situations. It really depends on input. 
As for styling, it's the matter of the preference... I personally don't like having a _valid_ case inside `catch`, or a huge catch-catch-catch chaining. Also exception is marginally more expensive to handle than `nil` returned by `decodeIfPresent` - yes, it's marginal difference, but still.